# How to preselect audio tracks in VLC when the language name is not in the track name?

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player

I have a number of videos that have been provided to me in multiple languages.  Unfortunately the first track is in Spanish and the second track is in English.  These audio tracks simply named `Track 1` and `Track 2` respectively.

I have attempted to use the standard option of setting it in the preferences:
[image]

However when I pick `EN` or even `Track 2` it simply will not default to the `Track 2` English track.  Any ideas on what may be going on here and how to force VLC to choose the correct audio tracks?

Comment: If the file is incorrectly tagged, there's no way to get a preferred language. Tap the 'b' key to rapidly cycle through languages - v key will do the same for subtitle languages. They're the 2 most worn keys on my media machine ;)

Comment: What file types are these - MKVs? You can easily change the default tracks or even remove the tracks that are not required.

Comment: https://misterhenson.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/vlc-media-player-set-default-audio-language-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use VLC's command line options:

Windows:

```
c:\ProgramFiles\VideoLAN\VLC.EXE --audio-track 1 VIDEO.MKV
```

OS X:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --audio-track 1 VIDEO.MKV
```

option `--audio-track x` where `x = [0..n]` (starting with zero)

Comment: Nice to know.  Useful, but not the solution in this case.  It appears that I need to modify all of the tags for these particular files.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX setting the preferred audio language works for me (MKV), do you have the newest version installed?

You can however use MKVToolNix to either reorder the audio streams so that the english track comes first or you can try using the header editor to add default flags to the tracks (which never worked for me with VLC)

https://mkvtoolnix.download